# PrlSF file-system on Mac?

Tags: mac, filesystems

A specific Windows app shows the file-system on my Mac as "PrlSF":

[image]

I did not find any information about "PrlSF". Is that another name of Mac-Filesystem? Where can I find information about it?

Comment: PrlSF is a Parallels shared folder. It is not a 'real' filesystem as such. How are you accessing this 'drive'?

Comment: From a Parallels VM (Windows).

Comment: Then ignore it, don't try to fix it or change it, Parallels is handling it for you.

Comment: The question arose today when I installed Dropbox in the Windows VM. A Dropbox message told me that it could not install the Dropbox folder on a Mac network share ("PrlSF"), only on NTFS.

Comment: I certainly will not change it. I am just curious.

Comment: Then that's the question you should ask about. I don't know the intricacies od Dropbox folder structures, but I doubt it's smart enough to use a virtual shared drive.

Comment: That's not about Dropbox folder structures. In Dropbox settings, you can select a simple local directory (which I then did inside the VM). You can even select a directory on a network share, but then it says only NTFS.